# how to make masterPage contents visible based on role?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, roles, master-pages

I am developing an application with masterPage.

I want to put loginStatus, LoginName controls into masterPage.

now, I want these loginStatus and LoginName controls be visible only if the user is admin.
(admin will exclusively navigate to login page and no Login/logout link, logged in username should be shown for non-admins)

how can I achieve this?

Comment: `if (admin) { myControl.Visible = true; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a LoginView, which supports roles:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
    <RoleGroups>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Admin">

        </asp:RoleGroup>
    </RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to know more about your authentication setup, but if you're using the standard ASP.NET role manager, you should be able to do something like this:

```
loginControl.Visible = Page.User.IsInRole("Admin"); //or whatever the role is
```

Answer (score 0):

check the users role

```
    if (Page.User.IsInRole("admin"))
    {
        loginStatus.Visible = true;
    }
```